# TemplateManager.GetTemplates always returning null

Tags: templates, sitecore-api

Got the following call:

```cs
var templatePath = "/User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Links";
var template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate(templatePath, Context.Database);
```

This is always returning null. I have checked the template path and can confirm 100% it is correct, the database is also present. This issue is happening in 8.2 any ideas on what I might be missing?

### Immediate Window Debug Information

```
Context.Database
{web}
    Aliases: {Sitecore.Data.AliasResolver}
    ArchiveNames: Count = 2
    Archives: {Sitecore.Data.Archiving.DataArchives}
    Branches: {Sitecore.Data.BranchRecords}
    Caches: {Sitecore.Data.DatabaseCaches}
    ConnectionStringName: "web"
    DataManager: {Sitecore.Data.DataManager}
    DataProviders: Count = 1
    Engines: {Sitecore.Data.DatabaseEngines}
    HasContentItem: true
    Icon: "Images/database_web.png"
    Items: {Sitecore.Data.ItemRecords}
    Languages: {Sitecore.Globalization.Language[1]}
    Masters: {Sitecore.Data.BranchRecords}
    Name: "web"
    NotificationProvider: null
    Properties: {Sitecore.Data.DatabaseProperties}
    Protected: false
    ProxiesEnabled: false
    ProxyDataProvider: {Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerProxyDataProvider}
    PublishVirtualItems: true
    ReadOnly: false
    RemoteEvents: {Sitecore.Data.Eventing.DatabaseRemoteEvents}
    Resources: {Sitecore.Resources.ResourceItems}
    SecurityEnabled: true
    "sitecore": sitecore (en#1@web), id: {11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}
    Templates: {Sitecore.Data.TemplateRecords}
    WorkflowProvider: null

TemplateManager.GetTemplate("/sitecore/Templates/User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Icon Links", Context.Database)
null
TemplateManager.GetTemplate("/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Icon Links", Context.Database)
null
TemplateManager.GetTemplate("User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Icon Links", Context.Database)
null
```

**Snip of item path, on web database.**

[image]

### Update

```
TemplateManager.GetTemplate("/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Standard template", Context.Database)
null
```

Using immediate window to try and get standard template also fails.

Comment: You probably have checked but is the template published? Are there any publishing restrictions?

Comment: Also worth trying to get a standard template to verify that your code is correct

Comment: @MichaelEdwards yes 100% the template is published.

Comment: Absolute paths will fail. Consistently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yea. Change your code to this:

```cs
var templatePath = "User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Links";
var template = TemplateManager.GetTemplate(templatePath, Context.Database);
```

If your path starts with "/", Sitecore will assume it to be absolute.

Comment: Also worth noting, that the templatePath parameter is case sensitive.

Comment: "User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Icon Links" doesn't work however "sitecore/Templates/User Defined/Project/Common/Content Types/Icon Links" does. Sad Times. Sorry tested both before but when testing relative path might of forgot to publish solution :P.

Comment: I can't reproduce. On a vanilla 8.2u0, relative path resolution always succeeds.

Comment: I will check over the configurations and dlls. They upgraded to 8.2 not sure how clean the upgrade was now.

Comment: Yeah it was just an out of date kernel binary sigh! What a waste of time! Part of the problem the right binary is referenced in solution, wrong one deployed :/.

Comment: Absolute paths are failing consistently also as you have stated.